# Как работает value в js или как удалить все value из input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

В общем нужно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, все что есть в input (то есть его value) удалялось.
Хотел сделать так: `var someIn = document.getElementById("inp").value`, но так оно не работает.
Как в таком случае можно удалить все что в input есть?

Так то приходится считывать весь элемент, хотя мне нужно только его value.

```js
function foo(){
  var inp = document.getElementById('someInp');
  inp.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="someInp">
<button onclick = 'foo()'>Enter</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: конечно чтобы работать с атрибутами объекта надо его считать. Это всё равно что говорить: мне надо с человеком поздороваться рукой, а он зачем-то весь целиком для этого передо мной стоИт, а не только рука. какая досада